# Does Swagger UI currently support models?

Tags: swagger

The Swagger Spec has provision for [describing a model](http://swagger.wordnik.com/spec#appendix-b).

However, the existing Swagger-UI project doesn't seem to consume it or display the model.
Looking at the [Petstore Demo](http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/), I see that a [model is served](http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/pet.json), but can't see it displayed.

Am I missing something?  Or is it just not supported yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: swagger models visible in build 1.1.5 of [swagger-ui](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui).

The models aren't shown in the UI right now but are used for the swagger code generator [[1](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui)].  They'll be in the UI soon though and used for operations like POST, PUT and DELETE, as well as a cleaner way to visualize the GET responses.